# Broadcasting channels per transmitter

Tags: transmitter

Are television transmitters designed to broadcast two or more 6Mhz channels? Do commercial broadcasters do it in practice? If so, what are the limits (2, 3, 4... channels)?

Comment: To people who voted to close: although the question doesn't seem particularly researched, it is not something about *the use* of electronic devices, as intended with that close reason. The OP is not asking how to tweak the settings of, say, his iPhone or his guitar amplifier. It is about capabilities of RF power transmitter and organization of commercial broadcast network systems. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I am asking a serious question about the technical possibilities of transmitter equipment. Please read before putting on hold. . That is important for regulatory of the Tv Transmitters nor an electrical engeneer but an economist.  not asking about some gadget

Answer (score 1):

It is not common practice due to tuning issues and loss factors with large power broadcast antenna, but a diplexor can be used to combine NTSC and DTV in some situations. A multiplexor can combine several near the same frequency but complexity factors are great and tuned baluns are complex enough for one Tx with high power.

It is always a compromise to share an antenna with power losses in the combiner.